# Closing a popup Panel by clicking a button in its child panel

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

I have the following Panel hierarchy:

**Custom Panel 1** contains **PopupPanel** contains **DecklayoutPanel** contains **CustomPanel 2** contains **FlowPanel** contains **Button**.

How do i close the Custom Panel 1 or PopupPanel by clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

// CustomPanel2

```
class CustomPanel2 {
  @UiField Button closeButton;

  public CustomPanel2() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  public HasClickHandlers closeButton() {
    return closeButton;
  }
}
```

// CustomPanel1

```
class CustomPanel1 implements ClickHandler {
  @UiField PopupPanel myPopupPanel;
  @UiField CustomPanel2 customPanel2;

  public CustomPanel1() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    customPanel2.closeButton().addClickHandler(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
    myPopupPanel.hide();
  }
}
```